# How to detect USB webcam in Android application?

Tags: android, mobile, usb, device, webcam

In my application I have a requirement to detect and capture images from external USB webcam in Android. I have tried with some open source libraries but no luck.

Can anyone suggest/ guide to detect and capture images from is webiin Android?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this paid library, we are using it for a product.
http://www.infinitegra.co.jp/en/solution/AndCamULib2.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is there any trail SDK with this library. I didn't find any trail version.

Comment: The trial library is a play store download at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=infinitegra.usb.video.app&hl=en . The pro version is the paid version, need to email infinitegra for the pro pricing .

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried to reach them but no one is responding. Meanwhile I found opensource libuvc library and tried with that to capture the image using usb cam. I am able to detect the attached device and if i click on ok button after selection of device app gers crashed. I don't know why. Can you please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 0):

For API 21+, [the `camera2` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) has a few things you can check to get started:

- Check if [the camera id](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#getCameraIdList()) is a non-integer:

  > Non-removable cameras use integers starting at 0 for their identifiers, while removable cameras have a unique identifier for each individual device, even if they are the same model.
- Check for [`LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL) (API 23+):

  > The camera device is an external camera, and has no fixed facing relative to the device's screen.
- Check for [`INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL) (API 28+):

  > This camera device is backed by an external camera connected to this Android device.

I haven't tested these out, but hopefully it's a start. [`LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL) looks like your best bet.